# Query error for query containing a column named "order"

Tags: sql, mysql, mysql-error-1064

For the life of me i can seem to figure it out

```
INSERT INTO category SET CategoryName = 'Hardware_1',
Category = 'HARDWARE', Status = '1', Order = '1'

 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that 
 corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax 
 to use near 'Order = '1'' at line 1

CREATE TABLE `category` (
  `CategoryID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `CategoryName` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `Category` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `Status` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `Order` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`CategoryID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: +1 for providing the query and `CREATE TABLE` script.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I write SQL for a table that shares the same name as a protected keyword in MySql?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10706920/how-can-i-write-sql-for-a-table-that-shares-the-same-name-as-a-protected-keyword)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Order` is a reserved word.  Enclose Order in backticks if you intend to use it.

```
INSERT INTO category SET CategoryName = 'Hardware_1',
Category = 'HARDWARE', Status = '1', `Order` = '1'
```

Comment: you're right about it being a reserved word but the SET syntax with an INSERT statement is indeed valid.

Comment: Side note: Just enclose all fields in backticks, especially if you're generating this query. It's safer.

Comment: Hmm... I have never used that syntax... I just checked the docs out. +1 for you and an edited answer. :-)  Thanks!

Comment: While the Set syntax is apparently valid, you might consider mving to the more standard values clause. It would inthe long run be easier to maintain and will be more portable if you need to change datbase backends as the Set syntax is not valid in other databases.

Answer (score 6):

As Cfreak pointed out in the comments, your syntax is valid. It's your use of the unescaped Order keyword that is the issue.

```
Insert Into category (CategoryName, Category, Status, `Order`)
Values ('Hardware_1', 'HARDWARE', '1', '1')
```

Comment: as I commented with everyone else. SET syntax is valid in an insert statement

Comment: @Cfreak, you're right. I've never used that syntax before. I'm use to MSSQL :P. Thanks, updated answer

Answer (score 3):

```
INSERT
INTO    category (CategoryName, Category, Status, `Order`)
VALUES  ('Hardware_1', 'HARDWARE', 1, 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

order is a reserved word in sql, you proably need to escape that column name:

```
INSERT INTO category SET CategoryName = 'Hardware_1', Category = 'HARDWARE', Status = '1', [Order] = '1'
```