# PHP PDO MySQL Syntax Error 1064

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I've encountered an error when uploading an application from my local machine to a development server. I'm attempting to insert a record into a table which works locally (WAMP, PHP 5.4.3, MySQL 5.5.24) but it fails on the development server (IIS, PHP 5.3.2, MySQL 5.0.88).

My query is:

```
$SQL="INSERT INTO log(`dev_id`,`website_id`,`time_entered`,`location`,`page`,`reason`,`backup_file`,`status`) VALUES('".$DevID."','".$WebsiteID."','".time()."','".$Location."','".$Page."','".$Reason."','".$BackupFile."','".$Status."')";
```

As you can see I've backticked the fields, because I thought it was that. I also quoted everything because I thought the unquoted numbers were causing the issue. I have also turned this into a prepared statement and have gotten the same error which is:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'log(`dev_id`,`website_id`,`time_entered`,`location`,`page`,`reason`,`backup_file' at line 1
```

I've looked all around for a solution and it seems that error 1064 is a tricky one. I'm assuming it has to do with the massive difference in software versions.

Comment: Actually the problem was the table name. "log" seems to be a reserved word (possibly in that version of MySQL?) either though I could not find it on the reserved word list. I just had to backtick it.

Comment: That is odd since I tried it and it worked without backticks

Comment: You're using PDO, but you're doing it **COMPLETELY WRONG**. Please read up on how to use [SQL placeholders](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) immediately before you do yourself some serious harm.

Comment: I'm aware. I was only doing this to test the issue. I am properly using prepared statements in my code.

Comment: @JasonKaczmarsky For your information 'log' is an reserved word. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replication-features-reserved-words.html

Comment: Remember that code like this has a way of weaselling into production somehow and also serves as a very bad example for others that are still learning. Please be responsible and **always** use placeholders.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I write SQL for a table that shares the same name as a protected keyword in MySql?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10706920/how-can-i-write-sql-for-a-table-that-shares-the-same-name-as-a-protected-keyword)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Table names that are reserved keywords need to be escaped, too.

```
INSERT INTO `log` (...)
```

What you've done there is akin to making a call to the [LOG](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_log) function.

Comment: Ah I was wondering why it was reserved. Thanks!

Comment: MySQL has a large number of [reserved words](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysqld-version-reference/en/mysqld-version-reference-reservedwords-5-5.html) which you can either work around by finding synonyms or by escaping.

Comment: I looked at this list, but did not find 'log' in the table so I thought it was safe.

Comment: It was probably interpreted as a function because you didn't include a space between `LOG` and the bracket as you're technically supposed to.

Comment: Oh I see, well I guess I learned something today. Thanks!