# PHP : MySQL insert into not working

Tags: php, mysql, insert, pdo

I cannot figure out why my insert into query is not working... Here is my code :

```
<?php
session_start();
try
{
$bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=gestion', 'root', '');
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
die('Erreur : '.$e->getMessage());
}

$req = $bdd->prepare('INSERT INTO tasks (title, details, maturity, from, to) VALUES(:title, :details, :maturity, :from, :to)');
$req->execute(array(
                    ':title'=>$_POST['title'],
                    ':details'=>$_POST['details'],
                    ':maturity'=>$_POST['maturity'],
                    ':from'=>$_SESSION['login'],
                    ':to'=>$_POST['to']
                    ));

header('Location: tasks.php');
?>
```

Nothing is happening when this code is runned.

Thank you for your help.

ANSWER :

`FROM` and `TO` are both reserved words... So, I cannot use them this way.

Comment: `FROM` and `TO` are both [MysQL reserved keywords](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html). You need to quote them with backticks to use as column names.

Comment: Could you catch the sql error?

Comment: Remove the `header()` and check the error message.

Comment: @Bigood It's PDO. So OP needs to check `print_r($bdd->errorInfo())`

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski My bad, just edited!

Comment: You are already using exceptions for connection errors. Configure PDO to use exceptions for everything.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I write SQL for a table that shares the same name as a protected keyword in MySql?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10706920/how-can-i-write-sql-for-a-table-that-shares-the-same-name-as-a-protected-keyword)

Answer (score 0):

from and to are reserved keywords in mysql.

You can use 'from' and 'to' in mysql....but you'll  have to wrap them with this character: ` (left of the 1 key on top of the keyboard)

so write `from` instead of from, and `to` instead of to