# Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object

Tags: php, mysql

This has been resolved thanks to raina77ow.
The from and to were messing the prepared statement up.

I have looked over this for the past 6 hours and I can not get this parametrized statement to work. However i have other parametrized statements that are working which look exactly like this. I know there is something wrong with my prepared statement but I cant seem to find the error. Can someone with a pair of fresh eyes help me?

```
function insert_event($post_id, $title, $location, $from, $to, $description)
 {
//open connection to database
$mysqli = db_connect();

//insert
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO Events (".
        "postID, ".
        "title, ".
        "location, ".
        "from, ".
        "to, ".
        "description) ".
        "VALUES (".
        "'$post_id', ".
        "?, ".
        "?, ".
        "?, ".
        "?, ".
        "?)");

$stmt->bind_param("sssss", $title, $location, $from, $to, $description);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
// close connection
$mysqli->close();
}
```

I have even tried this

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO Events (postID, title, location, from, to, description) VALUES ($post_id, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
```

sorry if its so easy to see whats wrong

Comment: Apparently there is an error with `prepare`

Comment: Isn't it because `FROM` and `TO` are [reserved words](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) in MySQL, I wonder? Quote these (wrap in ```), and it should work.

Comment: THANK YOU RAINA77ow!!!!! I changed the from and to and it now works. I just wasted 6 hours of my life. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why do you have `"'$post_id', ".` in a prepared statement?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15447133/mysqli-update-throwing-call-to-a-member-function-bind-param-error

Comment: now let us all go and hunt down and vote up raina answers!

Comment: @MarkBaker because the user does not enter the post ID. Is that bad programming practice?

Comment: It's inconsistent for a start, but including it as a bind variable alongside the other bind variables would be a lot cleaner, and internally consistent within the scope of the function where you can't see where $post_id comes from

Comment: Alright thanks for the suggestion. Still pretty new to PHP and mysql

Comment: @user1536365 - At least you're starting with prepared statements and bind variables, it's always sensible to learn good practises from the very beginning rather than learning bad practises

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I write SQL for a table that shares the same name as a protected keyword in MySql?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10706920/how-can-i-write-sql-for-a-table-that-shares-the-same-name-as-a-protected-keyword)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two reserved keywords in your prepare, they are `from` and `to` so just surround them with backtick to let mysql understand they are fields

```
    "location, ".
    "`from`, ".
    "`to`, ".
    "description) ".
```

Comment: or better yet, don't use any reserved words as `select 'from' from mytable` is just going to confuse people further down the line